# Can I split an iOS app to Two or more projects?

Tags: ios, swift, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

Working on an iOS app that can be divided in to two apps 
which will implement, one with Swift and the other with Appcelerator. 
**is that possible ?**

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible, but you cannot share code between the 2 apps unless you use Hyperloop by Appcelerator (Which requires a Pro account).

Appcelerator is a tool to build cross platform apps using JavaScript with a layer to translate it to Objective-C and Java.

Comment: Is there a life example of such approach ?!

Comment: the Titanium app will need to be written from scratch, in Javascript. Existing code can be used if you use Hyperloop to expose the code to javascript, but the app itself will still need to be made in JS